# Usage of "she" to refer to a noun

Tags: pronouns

I was alway get confused when I read something like this:

> "Because the attacker controls **her** end on the SSL tunnel, **she** can send anything **she** likes to the server..."

My instant reaction is to go back some paragraphs to check if I lost any reference to "the attacker" being female. Needless to say, most times there is no reference. I've seen phrases written like this everywhere, from newspapers and books to blogs.

So if I want to refer to a previous gender-neutral noun, should I always use a feminine pronoun? Is this a gramatical rule? Or does this belong in the realm of style?

Comment: If the phrase was 'the attacker controls **his** end' would you turn back to confirm the attacker is male? Until recently the male gender would be used without thought; the use of _she/her_ is likely a deliberate attempt to redress this. I would say it's certainly style rather than rule. The gender-neutral alternatives - 'controls **their** end', '**they** can send' often sound clunky or even misleading.

Comment: I think whoever wrote that line succeeded. Why assume the attacker is male? Why shouldn't we be talking about a hypothetical female hacker? And most of all — why should it confuse you? Are your gender biases challenged? I wouldn't bat an eye if the pronoun used was their/they, and it doesn't sound clunky to my ear, although some would disagree.

Comment: PS. The title of this question is misleading. "She" is emphatically *not* referring to just a noun. It is referring to a hypothetical *person* — the hacker. In this case, it is wholly appropriate to use a gendered pronoun, even if the gender of the attacker is not explicit.

Comment: @ghoppe, re 'their/they': it could be misconstrued as plural where singular is intended. That's my only gripe.

Comment: It confuses me because I learned that English words are gender-neutral. If I had to write something like that, I also wouldn't know what pronoun to use. So when I read it, I'm confused.

Comment: @Snubian Indeed, but I think in this particular case it's not an issue, since the plurality of the attacker/s is irrelevant. There could very well be a team of attackers on the other end of the line, how would we know? :)

Comment: @ghoppe, I see your point and I'm being pedantic, but 'the attacker controls their end' (note the singular _attacker_) doesn't sit properly with me. Certainly personal preference.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This belongs in the realm of style. If the people in examples are always male, then that tends to create a sense that we are excluding half the human race. When I need to use examples in any written communication or documentation, I use "she" in some examples and "he" in others. Always consistently, of course; the same example person does not shift between being a "he" and "she".

Traditionally, English used male pronouns in hypothetical examples about imaginary people. "Let he who is without sin cast the first stone." Using female examples is a modern way of eliminating sex bias from writing.

In writing from fifty or more years ago, you will not easily find these feminine examples. The male bias in the language used in the media decades ago is almost shocking.

For instance, take a look at page 8A in the advertizing section of the [March 1940 Popular Mechanics](http://books.google.com/books?id=btkDAAAAMBAJ). We find this:

> In fact probably most of the men who study law today have no idea of taking the bar examination or becoming lawyers---they want law training to give the mastery of men and situations in business. You know that:
>   (1) the man with legal training is a leader---not a follower [ ... ] (4) Many executive places are filled by men who have studied law. [...]

The words man and men appear in almost every sentence. The copywriter is devoid of any notion that women could study law or hold executive positions.

Comment: I find it interesting that choosing a pronoun can become a social issue in English and "create a sense that we are excluding half the human race."
It's something difficult for me to grasp, though. My first language is Portuguese and every word has a gender, so you just choose the pronoun that's adequate. It's a gramatical issue in Portuguese, not a style one. That's also why I'm confused, I tend to intepret the problem as a gramatical one.

There's a similar problem with some nouns in Portuguese that instead of being gender-neutral are in fact double gendered... but I digress.

Comment: @BeetleTheNeato, you may be a little confused here. The nouns in the passage ('attacker', 'SSL tunnel', 'server') are gender-neutral and are not modified or affected by the choice of male or female for the hypothetical attacker. Surely in Portuguese you would have the same issue of having to choose a gender when writing, say, a technical manual or user guide?

Comment: @Snubian Not really. Most nouns in Portuguese don't leave you any options. The word carries its gender onward. For example, "server" would translate to "servidor" which is a masculine noun, so you must you masculine pronouns to refer it (or you incur in a grammatical error).

Comment: @BeetleTheNeato I do have functional fluency in portuguese. Isn't *atacante* male or female? This is the word referred to by *she*. I really don't understand why you're confused by this issue.

Comment: [cont]

You do have a choice when dealing with double gendered nouns, but you choose the article that precedes it, not the pronoun. For example, "student" is "estudante" and the gender of the word depends on the article before it: "o estudante"(m) or "a estudante"(f). The most common way to deal with this issue in Portuguese when it occurs is to use "o/a estudante". Because few words happen to be double gendered, it's not really a problem to occasionally use the slash.

Comment: @BeetleTheNeato we so the same thing in english with s/he. But this becomes tiresome. It's simpler for the writer to imagine a gender and then be consistent.

Comment: @BeetleTheNeato There are nouns with gender in English. For instance *waiter* (versus *waitress*). Nowadays, we are supposed to refer to women servers as *waiter* also.  It is now possible to treat *waiter* just like *attacker*; introduce a person who is a waiter, and then later refer to that using *she*. Fifty or a hundred years ago, that would have jangled like bad grammar.

Comment: @BeetleTheNeato: Imagine a person walks into a cafe. She sat at the table. He sat at the table. Surely either of these sentences could be translated to Portuguese and be quite valid. I understand that the noun 'table' has a gender, but this doesn't influence the gender of the person who sits at it. It's the gender of the person we're talking about here, not the table.

Comment: Hey, guys, I find this all very amusing but I don't want to further escape the scope of the question. Would you mind pointing me to some relevant resources about this by PM? Thanks a lot.

Comment: @Snubian Well, not really. Beetle has a point there. If the word for *person* has a gender, then you have to stick with it!

Comment: Yes, the word for "person" is "pessoa" which is female.

Comment: @BeetleTheNeato Which I found delightful when I first learned the word!

Comment: In Slovak, there is a word for for individual ("osoba") which is feminine. It's a very impersonal word used when the speaker distances herself from the subject, like in news reports. There is also "človek", which means "human being".  That word is male. "osoba si sadla ku stolu" (The individual (she) sat at the table). "človek si sadol ku stolu" (The person (he) sat at the table). You cannot say "osoba si sadol ..."; it is laughably ungrammatical. The verb's third person past tense has a gender which has to match the subject.

Comment: Just a very curious side note... The idea of every word having a gender in Portuguese (and in many other languages) is usually quite difficult for someone whose first language is English to understand. It's common for foreigners to simply stick with one article and one pronoun and that often leads to some funny phrases.

Comment: @Kaz, this is getting a bit long-winded, but ... we're not talking about the noun 'person' here, which I accept has a gender. The question (as I interpret it) is asking about the choice between using _she_ or _he_ for a hypothetical, gender-optional character. My point is that this choice is made irrespective of whatever gendered nouns are present. Certainly if a choice of gender is implied by a previous sentence then stick with it, but that's not stated in the question.

Comment: @Snubian I guess I understand your point... For instance, in the phrase I quoted, "attacker" could be translated to "atacante". If you do choose to stick with "atacante" when translating the sentence, you'll have to choose an article. Articles in Portuguese can't be gender-neutral, so you'd be facing a similar problem: should it be translated as "o atacante"(m) ou "a atacante"(f)? The solution here would be probably to avoid using "atacante" (which sounds awkward in this context anyway) and change the structure slightly for a more rich one in portuguese, something like: "Porque quem ataca...".

Answer (score 4):

Let me sidestep the busy discussion on the ethics of male, female, and gender-neutral pronouns to observe that in documentation about a conversation between two people, e.g., *a network transmission,* it is extremely convenient to cast one as female and one as male. That way, ordinary English pronouns (he, she, etc.) can be used unambiguously.

At least at one time, articles on encryption and key exchange [used](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alice_and_Bob) **A**lice and **B**ob as the primary actors. Unfortunately *homo sapiens* lacks a third sex for the eavesdropper (often **C**harlie).

Comment: That's very interesting! And "Charlie" is a very smart choice since it's both a common name for men and women. That's really cool.

Comment: I thought the eavesdropper in that scenario was usually referred to as "Eve".

Comment: Perhaps it would work for the cryptologists if they supposed *Charlie* to be a sentient robot (or "soul-less bionic clone", whatever floats their boat! :). Then *Alice, Bob, Charlie* could be *she, he, **it***.

Comment: @matthew: The link in my answer has a full list of common names, including Eve, but also Charlie and Chuck.